# Android ADT - Eclipse , how can I get an Android project inmy new ADT env?

Tags: android, adt

I had an issue w my disk , so I reinstalled ADTfrom scrath  (latest version : adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321)..

I cloned back my Android project from my repository into a folder bitbucket/my_project
How should I get it back into my ADT ?

should I create a new Android App project then import into it or
import the cloned project directly from the file system ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use EGit to import project from web. Importing from disk is really tricky because of many autogenerated by Android files (R.java etc).

Comment: Thanjs ! It was the missing trick.... I did not remember my first import from git... and I did not take any note of it .. now it's engraved in my notes